# How can i hide a list in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program which involves hiding lists.
Can someone give me the basic code for hiding a list in tkinter on Windows Python 3.5.

Comment: Hide... lists? From who? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about removing a widget from view, it depends on how you added it to the window:

### grid

`grid_forget` removes the window from view, and forgets how it was originally placed in the window. If you call `widget.grid()` at some later point, it will use default values for the attributes.

`grid_remove` removes the window from view, but *remembers* how it was originally placed in a window. If you call `widget.grid()` at some later point, it will use the previous values for the attributes.

`grid_remove` is the best option, since you can easily make the widget visible again exactly where it was

### pack

If you used `pack`, `pack_forget()` will remove the widget from view. Note that there is no way for `pack` to remember where the widget was.To make it visible again in exactly the same place typically requires that you explicitly set the options again (and often with different values than you originally used).

### place

If you use `place`, `place_forget()` will remove the widget from view. Like with `pack`, `place` won't remember where the widget originally was placed. Since `place` typically takes absolute values, putting the widget back to its original location is very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you show that list using `your_list.pack()` then use `your_list.pack_forget()`

If you show that list using `your_list.grid()` then use `your_list.grid_forget()`

If you show that list using `your_list.place()` then use `your_list.place_forget()`

Or maybe you need `your_list.lower()` to put it behind other widget.